# Docker build unable to find settings.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I have problem while reading from settings.xml while docker image creation

Docker file

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-jammy

COPY .mvn/ .mvn
COPY mvnw pom.xml ./
COPY mvnw settings.xml ./
RUN ./mvnw -s settings.xml dependency: resolve

COPY src ./src

CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]
```

I tried this docker file also

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-jammy

COPY .mvn/ .mvn
COPY mvnw ./
COPY pom.xml ./
COPY settings.xml ./
RUN ./mvnw -s settings.xml dependency: resolve

COPY src ./src

CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]
```

and getting this error:

> Could not find goal '' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.3.0 among available goals analyze, analyze-dep-mgt, analyze-duplicate, analyze-only, analyze-report, build-classpath, collect, copy, copy-dependencies, display-ancestors, get, go-offline, help, list, list-classes, list-repositories, properties, purge-local-r
> epository, resolve, resolve-plugins, sources, tree, unpack, unpack-dependencies -> [Help 1]
> #14 64.62 [ERROR]
> #14 64.62 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> #14 64.62 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> #14 64.62 [ERROR]
> #14 64.62 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible   solutions, please read the following articles:
> #14 64.62 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException

Comment: Should you just copy the file? And remove the "mvnw" command from the copy statements.

Comment: I tried like that but not getting

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-jammy

WORKDIR /app
COPY mvnw .
COPY pom.xml .
# assume settings.xml is in current directory 
COPY settings.xml .
RUN mvnw -s settings.xml dependency:resolve

COPY src ./src

CMD ["mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]
```

Comment: I did this ,but then I got  CACHED [5/7] COPY settings.xml .                                                                               0.0s
 => ERROR [6/7] RUN mvnw -s settings.xml dependency:resolve                                                        0.6s
------
 > [6/7] RUN mvnw -s settings.xml dependency:resolve:
#13 0.608 /bin/sh: 1: mvnw: not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c mvnw -s settings.xml dependency:resolve]: exit code: 127

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: The title of the question is “Docker build unable to find settings.xml”. I am not ready to fix the project pom.